# Basic Fabric SSH Connection

Tags: python, ssh, connection, fabric, attributeerror

I just spent a lot of time trying to follow the basics of using fabric to establish a connection to a remote machine. I'm using a raspberry pi 3, it has python 2.7 installed on it, and fabric 1.13.1. I can successfully run a hello world function using a fabfile, but can't actually write a python script that establishes a connection to a remote machine, whether in the live python debugger or in a standalone python file. I dont even try to establish the connection. I just try to import Connection from fabric. Example:

```
from fabric import Connection
```

or

```
import fabric
c = fabric.Connection("192.168.0.1")
```

This always results in the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Connection'
```

I'm not sure what to do. When I look inside the directory of the fabric source, there is nothing named Connection. What am I doing wrong here?

Note: I am following the tutorial at: http://www.fabfile.org/

Comment: You just want to connect with localhost? or also try with database ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using Fabric v.1.X, in which the API is not OO, and the `fabric` module doesn't even have a `Connection` attribute.

In order to benefit from the `Connection` attribute, you have to use fabric v2.X, which is the version documented in fabfile.org

However, this version is not compatible with Python 2.X

If you really need to stick with Python 2.X, you have to use the `env` dictionary

```
from fabric.api import env

env.hosts = ['192.168.0.1']

# Your remaining code here
```

For more info, please refer to Fabric 1.13 docs [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/)